# How to show custom keyboard with alertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I need to show custom keyboard with alertDialog with editText;

I am using AlertDialog.Builder for creating new alertDialog.

After some time i can disable default keyboard, but i still can't show my own custom one...

here is some part of my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setTitle(mActivity.getString(R.string.title));
        builder.setMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.message));
builder.setNegativeButton(mActivity.getString(R.string.negative),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        mDialog = builder.create();
mDialog.show();

mDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
Keyboard_Digits kd = new Keyboard_Digits
                .Builder(mActivity, keboardView)
                .build();
        kd.showCustomKeyboard(mEditText);
```

this code open my custom keyboard, but is under dialog window.... (

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use PopupWindow.

```
PopupWindow popup;
final View custom = LayoutInflater.from(context)
.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, new FrameLayout(context));
popup = new PopupWindow(context);
```

The dialog it's not a good option for custom soft keyboards.